# How to stub a method when instance of specific object specific fields passed?

Tags: java, unit-testing, matcher, hamcrest

I want to return 4 when instance of Person class by [name = "Mohammad", age = 26] where called.
I want to return 5 when instance of Person class by [name = "Ali", age = 20] where called.

So I have these classes:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;
```

My DAO class:

```
public class DAO {
    public int getA(Person person) {
        return 1;
    }

    public int getB(Person person) {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Here is calculator class

```
   public class Calculator {
        private DAO dao;

        public int add() {
            dao = new DAO();
            return dao.getA(new Person("Mohammad", 26)) +
                    dao.getB(new Person("Ali", 20));
        }
    }
```

and this is my test:

```
    @Test
    public void testAdd() throws Exception {

        when(mydao.getA(new Person("Mohammad", 26))).thenReturn(4);
        when(mydao.getB(new Person("Ali", 20))).thenReturn(5);
        whenNew(DAO.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(mydao);

        assertEquals(9, cal.add());
    }
```

So why my test will failed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new Person("Mohammad", 26)` in `Calculator` class and `new Person("Mohammad", 26)` in your test class is not equal since you have not overwrite `equals` method in `Person` class.

Overwrite equals method in `Person` class as below

```
 @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Person person = (Person) o;

        if (age != person.age) return false;
        if (name != null ? !name.equals(person.name) : person.name != null) return false;

        return true;
    }
```

Overwriting `hashCode` is nesssacery when overwriting `equals()` methods

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure which testing framework you are using, but the instances of Person being used in the when() calls are not the same instances being used in your Calculator class so unless you are overriding equals() and hashcode() in Person they would not be considered as matching.

Your IDE should be able to generate suitable default equals() and hashcode() methods.